Getting the right output from a MATLAB script in Python
A Python script I'm working on calls a MATLAB script as a function, using the matlab.engine package, e.g. output=eng.Main_code_batch(H2,CO,CO2,CH4). The Matlab script in question looks like this:
function n=Main_code_batch(H2,CO,CO2,CH4)

format('long') %ensures all significant figures outputted
global R T P g obsern fug names; %define important variables as global for use in subsidiary functions
R = 8.3145; %Universal gas constant (Joules/Kelvin/mol)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% BEGIN INPUTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

T = 275.600869079658; %Average surface temperature on Mars (Kelvin)
P = 1.01325; %Average surface pressure on Mars (bar)

%option for gas fugacity coefficients
%fug='y' for inclusion of gas fugacities, 'n' for ideal gas behaviour
fug='y'; 

% IMPORTANT: Make sure there is one space after each species (e.g. type
% 'N2 ' and not 'N2' to ensure search function finds the correct species)
names={'H2 ', 'CO ', 'CO2 ','CH4 '};
n=[H2 CO CO CO2]';    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Call 'gibbs' function that obtains standard Gibbs free energy of
% formation for each molecular species at temperature, T.
g=gibbs(names,T);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Optional correction:
% change Argon abundance to ensure mixing ratios sum to exactly 1.
%missing = 1-sum(n,'double');
%n(3)=n(3)+missing;
% comment this section out if code is being modified for other planets
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

display('Initial mixing ratios')
obsern=n %store and print initial abundances as "obsern"

%Matrix with entries specifying the number of atoms of each element in
%each molecular species. Columns are the molecular species in "n", rows
%are the atmoms. Atoms and molecules have been labeled for clarity.
%       H2    CO    CO2   CH4
 a= [    0     1     1     1    ; %C
         0     1     2     0    ; %O
         2     0     0     4   ]; %H

%%% alternatively, call function that calculates 'a' matrix automatically
% rather than manually input matrix:
elements=makeAs(names);
a = cell2mat(elements(2:end,:))';
display(a);
% initial conditions for atom conservation constraint
b = a*n;

% Tolerance variables for optimization function:
tol = 1e-30; tol2 = 1e-60;

%Calculate Gibbs energy of initial (observed state)
G1 = totalGibbs(n);

%Find equilibrium state, n, and calculate Gibbs energy of equilibrium
%state, G2.
[n,G2,exitflag]=fmincon(@totalGibbs,n,[],[],a,b,repmat(1e-30,size(n)),repmat(Inf,size(n)),[],optimset('TolX',tol2,'TolFun',tol,'FunValCheck','on','Algorithm','interior-point'));
display('Final abundances')
n

% Calculate available Gibbs free energy (difference between final and
% inital Gibbs free energy). Because initial abundances were mixing
% ratios, then Phi has units of joules per mole of atmosphere
display('Gibbs energy change')
Phi = G2-G1
%Call function that plots initial and final abundaces with histogram
%hist_plot(obsern,n);

end

Both the Python and MATLAB code work fine so far--however, main_code_batch always returns the final value of n (e.g., [[1359.0385715065506],[1.6559819781255116e-11],[1486.608090152417],[62981.77749601823]]), and what I actually want is the value for Phi. What's the best way to make sure that value gets returned to the Python script so I can use it?
(I have very, very little experience in MATLAB, so there may be an obvious solution to this, but I don't know what it is, alas).
Thanks!

Your MATLAB function doesn’t return any values. In the first line, specify the name of the output variable.
